# Google script to change the contents of a cell to a checked checkbox if the cell is "TRUE"

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

Beginner here. I have a google sheet in which columns L, M, and N can contain the following things: "TRUE", "FALSE", blank, something else. I would like to write a script that looks at columns L, M, and N, if the value in a cell is "TRUE", it inserts a checked checkbox, and if the value in a cell is "FALSE", it inserts an unchecked checkbox. If the cell contains anything else, I would like the script to leave it as is. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: L, M and N are columns not rows. Do you agree?

Comment: You mention `blank, something else` do you want it to be an unchecked box or do you want to leave it blank or something else?

Comment: @Cooper Yes, they are columns, not rows. I apologize!

Comment: If the cell is blank or something else (usually n/a), I want to leave it as is - so leave it blank if it is blank, leave it n/a if it is n/a, etc. Essentially, I do not want to script to consider these cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addCheckbox() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A11').activate();
  var value = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A11').getValue();
  if(value == "TRUE" || value == "FALSE" ){
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A11').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .requireCheckbox()
  .build());
}
};
```

Output before function:

[image]

Output after function:

[image]

Adjust it to your columns / rows.

Comment: I copied this function is as written into a google sheet I created with identical data shown here and it did not work. No error messages appeared, it just didn't change TRUE or FALSE to checkboxes.

Comment: Did you changed the column and row you checking? Also the values have to be as written.. ofc you can add or change to w/e

Comment: I created a new sheet to test it which contains all of the data in column A, cells 1, 2, and 4 as you have shown. I did write it as TRUE and FALSE. I'm not sure where else I could be messing it up.

Comment: Try to screenshot what you actually did.. it's working.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use a google app script to accomplish this, when you insert a checkbox all you have to do is type in the formula bar the formula you want. As long as it returns a true or false it will retain the checkbox.

Say column A contains a series of TRUE and other

In cell B1 you could put `=arrayformula(if(A:A=true,TRUE,FALSE))`

Then highlight column B right click last option is Data Validation and select Checkbox.

There is no reason to do this with a google app script... unless there is another part to this question.

Comment: I assume he using other part of Google app script so he need the function to do so.
but using Data Validation is probably the best use if you don't use GAS.

Comment: @YakirMalka Maybe, I was thinking he wasn't aware he could put a formula in a checkbox. He also mentions `blank, something else.` in his question and didn't specify what behavior he wanted for those things.

Comment: Thank you @CodeCamper. I didn't want to complicate things, but I actually would like this is script form. I have another script that automatically pulls things from tab1 to tab2 of my sheet. In tab1, the data in columns L-N appears as checkboxes. When it pulls to tab2, it becomes TRUE FALSE. I'd like to automate it to turn back to checkboxes, rather than adding another column.

Comment: @Jen If you copy data with the data validation you shouldn't have to make them checkboxes again? If you are copying data from tab1 to tab2 are you copying the entire cell, why just copy values?

Comment: @CodeCamper, yes, that would solve the problem too. My script to copy the data is too long to fit here in entirety, but here is some of it: function screened() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PENDING-IP'); 
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('G:G'); 
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('SCREENED - READY FOR REVIEW'); 
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

Comment: @CodeCamper continued: for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Screened - Ready for Review') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
  j.push(i);
 }
 }

Comment: @Jen you should ask a new question such as how to copy a cell while retaining it's data validation in app scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function addCheckboxAll() {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .requireCheckbox()
    .build()
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1:A').setDataValidation(rule);
};
```

if you only want to define checkboxes on true/false cells

```
function addCheckbox() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1:A')
  var values = rng.getValues()
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .requireCheckbox()
    .build()
  var rules=[]
  values.forEach(function(val){
    if (val==true || val==false){rules.push([null])}else{rules.push([rule])}
  })
  rng.setDataValidations(rules)
};
```